# How to scan with clamscan files owned by other users without using root?

Tags: linux, permissions, anti-virus, cron, clamav

I've got clamav installed on a headless Debian server. It is not running a mail-server so I do not have `clamd` (`clamav-daemon`) running. The server has a Samba share (`/data`) that various Windows 7 and Windows 10 boxes will be mapping.

There will be numerous Samba users and so the files/folders in `/data` will be owned by various accounts/groups.

There will be files/folders that the `clamav` account will not have permissions to read.

I want to create a daily cron job that will use `clamscan` to scan `/data` but I don't want to run `clamscan` as `root` because documentation and numerous articles says not to run ClamAV as `root`.

I have tested the scan by running `clamscan` as `root` so I know it works but not sure how to get it to work without running as `root`.

I'm not sure where to start or what to do. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sudo, like what is suggested by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131868). In this case, you can set the exact command to be run by the user.

You need the superuser access, as a user could have set a `700` permission, so that any other user cannot access to his files, unless they have superuser power.

Edit: Without root access / sudo, you can't have a full access to all files/directories, as users may change the group of the files and/or directories, and the permissions of them. In this case, a normal user can't access as it doesn't have the privilege, so it's not possible. Running clamav with sudo, though, allows you to run only clamav with full access (i.e. override the `x00` permission access).

Comment: The question specifically asks about doing this without `root` privileges. (I don't think there's any way to do that, though.)

Comment: @tripleee yeah, I edited the question to add your point. Thanks